# Обращение к переменной в обфусцированном коде

Tags: javascript

Как я могу обратиться к переменной в обфусцированном коде? Вот мне нужно получить значение переменной la:

```
var _0x3383 = ["jQuery", ...,"beforeunload"] 
!function (x, _) {
   function e() {
      // код работы всего проекта (функции, переменные и тд)
      var la = {};
   }
}(window, window[_0x3383[0]])
```

Но браузер ругается, что её, якобы, нет. Может Вы знаете, как это сделать?

Comment: если не можете поменять код, то ни как, переменная скрыта внутри функции

Comment: @ThisMan очень жаль, а, может, есть методы обхода данного ограничения?

Comment: неа, это на уровне языка заложено

Comment: можно в отладчике по шагам дойти до выполнения данной строчки, и после присвоения значения создать глобальную переменную

Comment: @Grundy да, это работает, но я хочу работать с содержимым переменной, которое постоянно меняется